# Autodesk Forge Viewer is not rendering SVF derived from IFC

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

IFC model has been uploaded and translated to SVF.

the problem is reproduced on https://autodesk-forge.github.io/forge-tutorial-postman/display_svf.html. The viewer is rendering forge logo indefinitely. The console shows an error:

> "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.children.length')"

We are experiencing this since Tuesday, 26 Oct, 2022 06:45 AM (GMT).

This is the body of the Translate Job Post API:

```
{
    "input": {
        "urn": "{{t4_ossEncodedSourceFileURN}}"
    },
    "output": {
           "formats": [
             {
               "type": "svf",
               "views": [
                 "2d", "3d"
               ],
               "advanced": {
                        "conversionMethod": "modern",
                        "buildingStoreys": "show",
                        "spaces": "show",
                        "openingElements" : "show"
               }
             }
           ]
         }
}
```

The same model is successfully presented when translated to SVF2.

We tested this executing multiple scenarios using multiple models.

Using postman collections, both versions with signedcookies and without show the same behavior.

In our system , we are translating models to SVF and downloading derivatives to serve those from our own servers. The same behavior is noticed there. We are using forge-server-utils version 8.3.4 for download

Also, [vscode-forge-tools](https://github.com/petrbroz/vscode-forge-tools) Visual Studio Code extension shows the same behavior.

Models translated before the date indicated above are rendered correctly.

Kindly asking for help, this has a big impact on our service.

Comment: Could you try v7.71 to see if it works? It looks like an issue I reported a few days ago.

Comment: Thanks for your kind confirmation! Our engineering team is working on a fix for this. We apologize for any inconvenience had caused to you.